# EmberJS Route event transition

Tags: ember.js

emberjs-1.0.0-rc-6.1

My controller :

```
Application.LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend({
        loginFailed: false,
        isProcessing: false,
        isSlowConnection: false,
        timeout: null,
        login: function() {
            /* some code */
        },
        success: function() {
            this.reset();
        },
        failure: function() {
            this.reset();
        },
        reset: function() {
            clearTimeout(this.get("timeout"));
            this.setProperties({
                isProcessing: false,
                isSlowConnection: false
            });
        }
    });
```

My Routing :

```
Application.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        setupController: function(controller, model) {
            controller.reset();
        },
        events: {
        }
    });
```

When I go to "/login" for the first time, setupController is called. However, I would like to use a event (like transition) to call controller.reset() everytime Application transition into login.

With 
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true

I can see "Transitionned into 'login'", "Transitionned into 'anotherPage'" in the console, so I would like to know if it's possible to get the event which trigger those logs, in my router.

Like :

```
Application.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        setupController: function(controller, model) {
            controller.reset();
        },
        events: {
            didTransition: function(reason) {
                 controller.reset();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to know if it's possible to get the event which trigger those logs, in my router.

You can hook into to the route's `activate` and `deactivate` hooks and call the controller methods from there, like this:

```
Application.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function() {
    this.controllerFor('login').send('reset');
  },
  deactivate: function() {
    this.controllerFor('login').send('reset');
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for those hooks !

Comment: is there a "afterActivate" hook?

Comment: @daniel1426 The 'activate' and 'deactivate' hooks are fired after the route has been activated/deactivated.

Comment: What about for if you try to load a route for the current active route? What event gets fired then?