# Run function once when visiting a route

Tags: ember.js

When I navigate to a route the `init` hook is called on the controller.

When I navigate away and then back to the route it is not.  How can I force a function to run on a controller everytime you visit it?

So the function below works the first time you access.  But subsequest calls don't transition to `manage.site`.

```
siteChanged : function() {
    var site = this.get('site');
    if(site) {
        this.transitionToRoute('manage.site', site);
    } else {
        this.transitionToRoute('manage');
    }
}.observes('site').on('init'),
```

Comment: i think its better to manage transitions in `redirect` hook of `router` rather `init` of `controller`.

Comment: @CodeJack in either case I have the same issue right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18082469/548568

Comment: @blessenm cool, will try that tomorrow

Comment: no..redirect will happen all the time..but init wont...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar use case to this, so here's what I did:

```
App.FooRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    activate: function() {
        Em.tryInvoke(this.get('controller'), 'activate');
    }
});

App.FooController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    activate: function() {
        // This controller's route was just activated
        // Perform any setup logic here
    }
});
```

Since controllers are singletons, I think it's perfectly valid design to tell the controller when it should reset its state. I would personally like a way for controllers not to be singletons*, but I'll use this for now.

* I'm sure there is a way by manipulating how it's looked up in the container, but this way works well enough for now.